# Use classes defined in a specification (JAX-RS) or defined in an implementation (Jersey)?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, specifications

I'm new at working with REST in java.
When examining an application that implements a REST service in java, I saw classes that where defined in the `javax.ws.rs` package.

As I understand it, JAX-RS is a specification and in order to use it, you need an implementation, eg Jersey.

How comes that the classes I see used in the application are JAX-RS classes, eg the `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` class.
Shouldn't the classes be Jersey-classes as stated before? 
Or is it possible to use the "specification-classes" directly?

I thought that all the classes I would see, would be classes from the Jersey API, but this is not the case.
Could someone explain when classes from a specification vs implementation are used?

Comment: The `Response` class to which you refer actually is abstract.  If you look in your code where it is being used, there must be some concrete implementation.  Perhaps that implementation is being provided by Jersey.

Comment: Refer to [this link](https://ashishontech.xyz/what-is-jax-rs/) for more in detail with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javax.ws.rs.core.Response` is part of JAX-RS API, i.e. a *specification*.

It's an abstract class, and as such can not be instantiated.

Jersey *implements* `Response` in `com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.ResponseImpl`. The actual name doesn't matter because you should instantiate a `Response` using the `ResponseBuilder` JAX-RS API.

For example:

`Response res = Response.ok().build();`

That internally will look up an implementation and instantiate it.

(If you only include the JAX-RS API, that call will fail at run time)

Comment: Thanks. I saw now in the web.xml file that an implementation was specified in a `<servlet>`. I assume this is how "internally looking up an implementation" works? That was part of the mystery for me, that I never saw the implementation mentioned in the classes themselves.

Comment: The lookup happens inside [`RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate()`](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxrs-api/blob/master/jaxrs-api/src/main/java/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.java#L99), it's a simple classpath search. As long as the implementation is on the classpath, it will just work.

Answer (score 0):

The specification is indeed just defining the API that any JAX-RS implementation, such as Jersey, should implement.

This API includes primarily interfaces (so no implementation) and annotations, which the users of the API could decorate their classes with, and the implementation is expected to process and handle accordingly.

As you rightly noticed, the API also defines some abstract or concrete classes. This is mostly used in places where the API is defining some data structures that the methods of the interfaces are expecting. It could also be the case that there is some minimal API level logic which the specification is enforcing. They were segregated into this `javax.ws.rs.core` package on purpose.

In your case [`Response`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) is an abstract class. In this specific case, the real reason could be simply because before Java 8 you weren't allowed to have a `static` method in an interface. And as you can see, it has a lot of `static` utility methods. It also provides a concrete instance method [`getHeaders()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#getHeaders--) which the designers think should probably always be the same (again after Java 8 this could have been a `default` interface method).

There are a [few other classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/package-summary.html) which probably exist for similar reasons, as support classes for the API.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea behind the specification is to allow applications to be developed using a "standard" API that can work on any compliant implementation, the point being that a `JAX-RS` application should work with minimal changes whether you're using Jersey, Reasteasy, or other implementations; and that makes them portable.

This is not specific to `JAX-RS`: the same can be said about `JAX-WS`, `Java EE`, `JDBC`, and many other specifications. It may be possible to use implementation-specific classes (some implementations even provide documentation for this), but portable JAX-RS code uses the standard API.